# Which app can be used by new account?

Tags: linux, permissions

There are two users in my os,the root and a normal user suppose it is the `name1`,login my os ,`name1` can use many apps,now i add a new user `name2`,which app used by `name1` can be used by `name2`?How can i block apps used by `name1` from being used by `name2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, software installed via a package manager such as `apt` or `yum` is available to all users (notwithstanding things reserved for use by `root`).  If you want a program to only be available to a specific user, that user can install it in its home directory by hand rather than using system tools

Comment: 1.Can root install the app for some specific user?How?

Comment: 2.How the user (himself or herself) install the app used privately ?

Comment: 1. Most easily, by `su`-into that user and, as that user, installing the application in that user's home directory as that user would.
2. By following the installation directions provided by the application's maintainer.  Often this might be with `make install --user` or some other option.  This varies wildly by the individual application and suchly "read the documentation" is the only truly comprehensive answer.

Comment: I knew two ways to install app in debian: apt install appname , dpkg -i  *.deb ,all of them need sudo permission.What does "by hand rather than using system tools" mean then?

Comment: In order to achieve my target -- used only by the user `name2`.The app can only be installed with ``./configure --prefix=/home/name2,make,make install`` way?